# Admob ad showing with java not showing with xml

Tags: java, android, xml, admob, ads

I had succefully saw an ad when i made it all from scratch in java, but when i try doing it by xml i just dont see anything

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<RadioGroup android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:id="@+id/options" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal">
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/option_length" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Length" android:checked="true"></RadioButton>
    <RadioButton android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Computers" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/option_comp" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"></RadioButton>
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/option_currency" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Currency" ></RadioButton>
</RadioGroup>
<RadioGroup android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:id="@+id/options1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal">
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/option_weight" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Weight"></RadioButton>    
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/option_volume" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Volume"></RadioButton>
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/option_temp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Temperature"></RadioButton>
</RadioGroup>

<RadioGroup android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:id="@+id/options2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal">
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/option_area" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Area"></RadioButton>    
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/option_time" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Time"></RadioButton>
</RadioGroup>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/mainButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Start Converting!"
    android:textSize="26sp"
    android:padding="50px"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    />

 <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     ads:adUnitId="a14e19f69861bf1"
     ads:adSize="BANNER" />
```

EDIT: Just saw this in the LocCat:

```
07-10 23:48:30.103: INFO/Ads(331): onFailedToReceiveAd(Ad request successful, but no ad returned due to lack of ad inventory.)
```

so i guess it's their fault??

Answer (score 2):

They don't always have enough ads to display. also you should add

```
ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
```

EDIT: Saw your comment yes it would be there fault